# Sending an email using sharepoint object model sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, email, object-model, event-receivers

i have been working on generating email in an event receiver using share point object model..i used the sputility.sendemail method..2 things are necessary in the email(email from and HTML body)..so i used the SpUtility method...

```
public static bool SendEmail(
SPWeb web,
StringDictionary messageHeaders,
string messageBody
```

)
but this method strips any HTML present in the body..so i looked same method diff parameters..

```
public static bool SendEmail(
SPWeb web,
bool fAppendHtmlTag,
bool fHtmlEncode,
string to,
string subject,
string htmlBody
```

)

```
public static bool SendEmail(
SPWeb web,
bool fAppendHtmlTag,
bool fHtmlEncode,
string to,
string subject,
string htmlBody,
bool appendFooter
```

)
the above functions do provide the html body but no 'from' parameter...how can i have both the 'from' and 'body(HTML support)' parameters..any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to specify headers in this way:

```
var headers = new StringDictionary();
headers.Add("subject", "Hi!");
// "text/html" to send rich html text in message body
headers.Add("content-type", "text/html");
headers.Add("to", "some@address.com");
headers.Add("from", "some@mail.com");
SPUtility.SendEmail(web, headers, "<b>Hi there!</b>");
```